# cyhper combine two columns into a single

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I couldn't find a similar post, so if you already know one or if my question is not the proper one, please let me know.

I have this query

```
MATCH
  (t:Taxi {name:'Taxi1813'})<-[:ASSIGNED]-(u2:User)-[rd2:DROP_OFF]->
  (g2:Grid)-[r:TO*1..2]-(g:Grid)<-[rd:DROP_OFF]-(u:User)-[:ASSIGNED]->(t)
WHERE ID(u2) < ID(u) AND rd2.time >= '04:38' AND rd2.time <= '04:42'
WITH DISTINCT u2, g2, u, g, rd2, rd
MATCH p=shortestPath((g2)-[r:TO*1..2]-(g))
WITH rd2, rd,u2, g2, u, g, p, REDUCE(totalTime = 0, x IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) | totalTime + x.time) AS totalTime
WHERE totalTime <= 4
RETURN u2.name, u.name
```

So at the end i got two columns

```
u2.name  u.name
User179  UserTest
User177  User179
```

Is there is a way or function to merge both columns into a single one and remove duplicates

```
Users
User179
User177
UserTest
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: BTW: I think you want `ID(u2) <> ID(u)` instead of `ID(u2) < ID(u)`.

Comment: i'm going to test it and let you know, thank you for your observation

Comment: The difference can be subtle. If you want to ensure that `u` and `u2` are different, then you need to make that change. Your current Cypher code does not do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine the two collections into a single collection and then return just the distinct items.

```
WITH ['User179', 'User177'] AS list1
, ['UserTest', 'User179'] AS list2
UNWIND list1 + list2 AS item
RETURN DISTINCT item
```

Alternatively, if you are using APOC you could use `apoc.coll.union()` instead.

```
WITH ['User179', 'User177'] AS list1
, ['UserTest', 'User179'] AS list2
RETURN apoc.coll.union(list1,list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

u2.name + u.name combines the list

you could make something like "where u2.name is not equal to u.name(not right syntax)"

Comment: Thank you @Mvde for your suggestion, i tried this u2.name <> u.name
RETURN u2.name + u.name as Users. But the condition didn't work out, may be i missed something. But i made it using the previous answer, thank you for your time and i hope to see you in the next posting :)